# Elements are going inside the nav bar css react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am making an app using react and it has gotta nav bar. So the problem is that my h1's and all the stuff are going inside the nav bar - when I mean that I mean that it is going through the nav bar -

```
    <nav class="header">
      <a href="" class="logo">
        INDUSTRIES
      </a>
      <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
      <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn">
        <span class="navicon"></span>
      </label>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/blogs">Text</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

and here is this css

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  color: #000;
}

/* header */

.header {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header li a:hover,
.header .menu-btn:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.header .logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* menu */

.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

/* menu icon */

.header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background 0.2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
}

/* menu btn */

.header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
  max-height: 240px;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}

/* 48em = 768px */

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .header li {
    float: left;
  }
  .header li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

So if ya run this code, you get that the h1's - bmw 4 series is going inside the program. How to fix that?

Comment: Bruh any answers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add `top: 0` to your `header` class.

```css
.header {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Please mark as accepted answer if this helps you. It is the tick in my answer.